# How do I reassign Activity records to a different Regarding record in another entity in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, etl, data-import

A client wants all Activity records assigned to records in a custom entity reassigned to the matching records in a different entity.

Basically, they have an old custom entity with Activities of various types assigned to those records. They decided to do away with the custom entity and instead go with the Opportunity entity because of its hooks into Lead. So the data from the custom entity was exported and re-imported back into Opportunity. But now I need to take all the Activity records and do the same, re-mapping them from the old custom entity records to the matching Opportunity record.

But there doesn't appear to be any intuitive method of doing this. What's the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already mapped the old entity to Opportunity, I figure they are 1:1.

Just make a small C# console program that retrieves all the activities from CRM,and FOREACH activity gets the old record, gets the relevant field (name, custom key, whatever) which helps you identify the equivalent opportunity, query the CRM for this opportunity, and link the activity with this Op.

Should be 1hr work(developing it). Like any bulk job in CRM, depending on the number of activities, it won't be the fastest program you ever wrote, but it's a one time job, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just perform a standard data import and set the owner in the source.

[Owner Mapping/User creation in Import Data Wizard for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/11/20/owner-mapping-user-creation-in-import-data-wizard-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online.aspx)